# Show navigation drawer menu item only when a Fragment is shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to show a button in the actionbar when a Fragment is shown and to hide the button when the other Fragment are shown.

I Override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_example);

         item.setVisible(true);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }
```

And use `setHasOptionMenu(true)`:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
```

I have done a test and I noticed that initially the button doesn't appear in the other Fragment , but after I open the Fragment in which I put this code above, the button is shown also in the other Fragment.

Comment: 2006 you have to use sethhasOptionMenu() for that fragment.make sure u are replacing the fragment not as stack

Comment: @Asthme the problem is when i use this code to replace the Fragment: `fragmentManager.popBackStack();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.container,SceltaDiete.newIstance(position + 1))
      .commit();`

Comment: try setHasOptionMenu(false) or create empty menu.xml with no items and setHasOptionMenu(true)..Please try and tell me

Comment: @Asthme I try your solution but it didn't work :(

Comment: use menu.clear() in onCreateOptionMenu(); in first line.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is removing the optionsMenu in the onDestroy of the fragment. The behaviour you describe is logical with your code: when the Fragment is created you also create the options menu. It will not automatically be destroyed when the Fragment is destroyed.